# Firefox transform origin bug on child elements svg

Tags: css, firefox, svg, snap.svg

I heard that from the 41st version of firefox transform-origin in css should work fine with svg but I had an issue today.

Here is what i've done :

Create polygons in my svg using snap.svg

```
var fdr = Snap('#fdright');
var fdh1 = fdr.polygon(185.551,171.956, 127.89,138.705, 127.89,72.203, 185.551,38.953, 243.212,72.203, 243.212,138.705).attr({fill:'#847b63'}).addClass('mixer');
var fdh2 = fdr.polygon(230.167,184.957, 214.77,176.079, 214.77,158.321, 230.167,149.443, 245.563,158.321, 245.563,176.079).attr({fill:'#bce06e', opacity:'0.9'}).addClass('ochange');
var fdh3 = fdr.polygon(251.981,208.411, 237.767,216.627, 223.561,208.425, 223.57,192.006, 237.785,183.79, 251.99,191.992).attr({fill:'#bce06e', opacity:'0.7'}).addClass('ochange');
var fdh4 = fdr.polygon(126.443,155.101, 107.259,166.191, 88.087,155.121, 88.098,132.962, 107.283,121.873, 126.455,132.943).attr({fill:'#bce06e', opacity:'0.6'}).addClass('ochange');
```

Here I have my polygons with class called "ochange"

Then this CSS :

```
.ochange{
transform:scale(1);
transition-duration:0.3s;
transform-origin:50% 50%;
}
.ochange:hover{
transform:scale(0.7);
}
```

In Chrome it works perfectly, when I hover a polygon, it scales down from its own center. 
But in firefox, the origin of the scaling is the svg space, making all polygons scale from the center of the container in which they are held.

Does anyone have an idea about how I should get around this bug? If possible I would like to avoid having to move all my polygons (I actually have more than 30). Is there a simple solution that doesn't involve making changes to each and every polygon?

Comment: I already have the same issue with several `<rect>` inside a `<g>`, and the only thing that worked is to not draw rect in their final position, but to draw them all in the same position, and translate them to the desired location.

Comment: The bug is in both your code and Chrome, not Firefox. See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box both you and Chrome have coded for a transform-box of fill-box whereas the specification says that the default transform-box is view-box

Comment: I think I get what you mean Robert, but I still can't make it work... If I understood it right I have to add : transform-box="fill-box" to each of my polygons for the transform's origin to be placed from my polygon's box. I have the feeling that my problem is that my polygons are governed by the CSS box model which should mean that my "fill-box" ends up as a "border-box", but how do I check that? Or do you mean that I shouldn't make my animation using css?

Comment: The former is what I meant. SVG polygons are never governed by the CSS box model. Set svg.transform-box.enabled in about:config to get transform-box support in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you, it worked great. But now I'm wondering -> The modification I made in about:config is only for firefox on my computer, right? So how do I make it work the right way when my website will be online?

Comment: As you are using Snap, why not use Snaps transform (which transforms by default around its center).

Comment: I'm quite new to snap, I don't really know if it's possible to make it so that a group of polygons will each scale down independantly when you hover them like you would do with a css class. But If it's possible, i'd be glad if you could give me some info about it ! Thanks you!

Comment: It would look something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/tjsdwh6L/4/

Comment: That's amazing, this selectAll/foreach will really be helpful! Thanks a lot Ian!